# unable to find the class path for jsp files

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp

Im using Tomcat 9.0. My problem is when I created Maven Project with an archetype of Group Id     -->org.apache.maven.archetypes 
   Artifact Id  -->maven-archetype-webapp
   version      -->1.0
the folder structure I got is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxWmU.png)

I created some jsp files under webapp folder all the jsp files are working fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcalc.png)

but when i created folders like jsp and css  under webapp directory none of my jsp files are working 
when i run these jsp files im getting error 404.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIOAR.png)

I think the folders i added are not added to classpath pls give me a solution

Comment: have you declared your servlets in the web.xml file?

Comment: @Leo R i used annotations (@WebServlet)

Comment: just (@WebServlet) ? or like this : @WebServlet("/Test")

Comment: yeah @WebServlet("/app") like this

Comment: Do you understood my problem the coding is fine,under webapp directory they all are working, when i make them into separate folders they are not working.